# Corresponding expression in C

Tags: c

I am currently learning C language and I come across this statement which seems to complex and confusing enough for me

*F is a function which receives nothing and returns pointer to an array of three pointers to function which returns character and receives no argument.*

what I came up with is

```
char (*(*f[3])())[3]
```

or

```
char (*(*f())[3])()
```

please help me if i am correct on this, or please suggest me

Comment: In the first one `f` is an array.

Comment: https://cdecl.org/?q=char+%28%2A%28%2Af%28%29%29%5B3%5D%29%28%29

Comment: and f receives nothing

Comment: @melpomene WOW, just amazed, you are great, it's just like magic, thank you-so much, I am glad that I was correct in the second solution

Comment: An empty argument list in a function prototype does *not* mean it takes no arguments.  It means that it takes unspecified arguments.  To indicate no arguments, you must use `void` as the argument list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char (*(*f[3])())[3];
```

That's an array of 3 function pointers `(*f[3])`  taking unspecified arguments `()` and returning a pointer to an array of 3 characters `char (*...)[3]`.

```
char (*(*f())[3])();
```

That's a function f `f()`, the returns a pointer to an array of 3 `(* ... )[3]` pointers to functions that take unspecified arguments `()` and return a char `char`.

I call that "unspecified arguments", because `()` in parameter-list in function declaration let's you call the function with any number and any type of arguments, if you want no arguments you do `(void)` in any C after C89, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration) for a short explanation.

So:

> F is a function which receives nothing and returns pointer to an array of three pointers to function which returns character and receives no argument.

would be:

```
char (*(*f(void))[3])(void);
```

Anyway, I say, you passed!

Comment: well explained, it is now more clear for me, thank you so much